# Only the alternate(even rows) are getting imported into the database in django

Tags: python, django, excel, xlsx, pyexcel

I'm working on an excel file upload in django
Using the same method I've populated another model using a xlsx file.But in the second model I cant upload and I'm facing an issue which I mentioned below.

> views.py

```
def import_source(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST,
                              request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.FILES['file'].save_to_database(
                name_columns_by_row=0,
                model=Tracker,
                mapdict=['sl_no','dot','branch','sname','snum','can_name','sdetail','main_skills','uname','cus_name','ep_num','day','doi','status','cont_num','email_id','texp','rexp','cu_org','cu_loc','pref_loc','cu_ctc','exp_ctc','notice_period'])
            return HttpResponse("OK")
        else:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest()
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(
        request,
        'upload_form.html',
        {'form': form})
```

> models.py

```
class Tracker(models.Model):
    sl_no = models.IntegerField()
    dot = models.DateTimeField()
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    snum = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    can_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sdetail = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    main_skills = models.TextField()
    uname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cus_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ep_num = models.CharField(max_length=200,primary_key=True)
    day = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    doi = models.DateTimeField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cont_num = models.IntegerField()
    email_id = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    texp = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=2)
    rexp = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=2)
    cu_org = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cu_loc = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pref_loc = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cu_ctc = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=2)
    exp_ctc = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=2)
    notice_period = models.IntegerField()
```

> Excel file
>   [.xlsx file which I'm tryig to upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxTjw.jpg)

in the above image only the rows with sl_no 1,3,5 are uploaded

> result
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0l8B.jpg)

Comment: that means the rest of your rows may have gotten an exception. Please checkout your django log. And what's more, if you could install pyexcel-io 0.4.2, which will throw exception in the first place, you may find the problem faster.

Comment: but the same code works for another model without an issue

Comment: That would tell django-excel works well for the other model of yours. However, for your Tracker model and its data import code, please treat it as a specific case. If the result is not what you expected, there must be a reason behind it. How django-excel works is to try bulk import first. If that fails, it will try to import one by one and throw out the ones that cause problems. That's the theory. To find what have happened, you need to find the evidence: log, debugging trace etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for the support !!@chfw
the code worked.
actually the problem was with the date format in the excel file. Django accepts yyyy-mm-dd, but the input date was in the format dd-mm-yyyy